# Show hidden element if their character length is less than 8

Tags: javascript, html, visibility, display, hidden-field

I have a hidden element called ShowUsername that I want to show if the user inputs a username that is less than 8 characters. I can't seem to figure this out if someone could help me out. I currently have the element hidden and it stays hidden if the string input is 8 or more characters.

```js
var myPassword = document.getElementById("Password");
var myUserName = document.getElementById("Username");

document.getElementById("frmRegister").onsubmit = function() {

  <!-- Username must be 8 or more characters -->
  if (myUserName.value.length >= 8) {
    alert("YOur Username was saved");
  } else {
    ShowUsername.display;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the html too?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a Stack Snippet with the JavaScript code you had provided. You may want to [edit] your question, and the snippet (there should be a "edit the above snippet" link below it) to add the HTML elements so that people can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Note that `ShowUsername.display;` does nothing. If you have an HTML element with the ID "ShowUsername` you could get away with `ShowUsername.style.display = "block";`...

Comment: What do you mean by hidden, `display:none;`, or `<input type='hidden' />`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.

```
ShowUsername.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

set the default display in html using `style="display:none;"` and use `style.display = 'block'` or `style = 'display:block;'` to show

example

```js
window.btn.onclick = function() {
  if (window.Username.value.length >= 8) {
    window.ShowUsername.style = 'display:none;';
    console.log("YOur Username was saved");
  } else {
    window.ShowUsername.style = 'display:block;';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="Username">
<div id="ShowUsername" style="display:none;"> min 8 chars</div>
<div><button id="btn" type="button">BTN</button></div>
```